# Update Query runs successfully in SQL but there are no changes in Database

Tags: python, sql

I have an update query to make some changes in the database, but unfortunately, it executes successfully and I see no changes in the database. What could be possibly wrong in a single line statement of SQL update query?

```
update_query = '''UPDATE air_programmes SET total_count = total_count + 1  WHERE  id='%s'
        ''' % resource_id
```

and resource id is a variable defined above!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In some databases, you need to issue a `commit` after the `update`.

Comment: Any rows that have that id?

Comment: When I run this query on my phpMyadmin it executes and I am able to see changes in that particular column but running it programmatically makes no update.

Answer (score 1):

You mention phpMyAdmin so I assume you're using MySQL with a db-api compliant connector (python-MySQL or mysql-connector-python etc).

First point: you need to explicitely commit your changes, ie:

```
connection = YourConnector.connect(**connection_info)
cursor = connection.cursor() 
update_query = """
  UPDATE air_programmes 
  SET total_count = total_count + 1  
  WHERE  id='%s'
  """ % resource_id 
cursor.execute(update_query)
connection.commit()
```

Of course if you have a whole batch of updates you may want to commit only once for the whole batch.

Second point: using Python string formatting to pass query arguments is brittle and [very unsafe](http://bobby-tables.com/). You really want to use the db-api to take care of proper sanitization of your query's params:

```
connection = YourConnector.connect(**connection_info)
cursor = connection.cursor() 
update_query = """
  UPDATE air_programmes 
  SET total_count = total_count + 1  
  WHERE  id='%s'
  """
cursor.execute(update_query, [resource_id]))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: @abhishek glad I could help - and do not hesitate to accept the answer then ;)